# Marking Event Points on a Pandas plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm plotting some 2-D time series data, and I want to mark specific dates on the plot with an X or some other marker.  For example, if I have all the data for each date running for the last 6 months, and I want to point out where Christmas was on this plot.  What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?  I can do it manually, but would prefer to add something that automates it in my code.

Edit:  My attempt at this so far. Not sure if there is anything the would work better.  I had some trouble comparing the date objects, which is why the comparison string is split up as it is.

```
filt1.plot(figsize=(16,16))
filt3=filtered[(filtered.index.year==2012)&(filtered.index.month==12)&(filtered.index.day==25)]["Income_MA"]
filt3.plot(style="ro")
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I edited my post with my current solution.

Comment: are you looking for `annotate` are `axvline`?

Comment: Annotate sounds perfect!  I was not aware of this feature, I will look into implementing it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Following up on tcaswell's comment, something like this might work for you?

```
df = pd.Series(np.random.rand(180), index=pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2000, 9, 1), periods=180, freq='D'))
xmas_date = pd.datetime(2000, 12, 25)

myax = df.cumsum().plot()
ylims = myax.get_ylim()
myax.vlines(xmas_date, ylims[0], ylims[1])
myax.annotate("Xmas", xy=(xmas_date, ylims[1]), 
              xytext=(-12, 5),
              textcoords='offset points')
myax.set_ylim(ylims)
```

Giving

[image]

This is a fragile solution because I've manually set a single date to annotate but it should be pretty easy to wrap that code in a function and call it for every date you're interested in.